# Correlation of entrance rank to subsequent performance

Tags: correlation, ranks

As part of my M Tech Thesis, I have to find the correlation between the Rank in Engineering Entrance Test and performance in 1st Year Engineering in terms of GPA i.e. Gross Performance Average. Can someone explain how this can be done ...

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to ask. Do you mean you want to know the formula?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Can you show us some of the data?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you should **plot your data**. A simple scatterplot would do. Look for outliers in the plot and maybe investigate those.

Then, you could calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient between the ranks and GPA. If you want some significance test you could maybe use permutation, for a confidence interval bootstrapping.